# .Net Maui Android TV (not computable)

Tags: maui, android-tv

I have develop an application using .Net MAUI and this app meant to support android TV with android phones.
I tried to search for a documntiation about make the app support android tv and I only found [this sample](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start)

```
<application
  android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
  ...
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

  </activity>
</application>
```

I tried to add it to the AndroidManifest.xml but I could built the solution, so I ended up adding the folowing line to MainActivity.cs

`[IntentFilter(actions: new string[] { "android.intent.action.MAIN" }, Categories = new string[] { "android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" })]`

This was the only approach to make the solution buildable again without errors

After that I was able to see my app icon on the TV emulator

Now when I uploaeded the new release with the android TV support on GooglePlay it said that now I have added over 1400 new tv device support, but the app still show "This item not compatible with your device"
and of course, it doesn't appear on google play on android tv.

So any one have anyidea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have no references to back this up. but when i hit the same problem i found that adding

```xml
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```

added support for those items
edit 1:
I came across a google link that supports this answer
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#no-touchscreen